# How can I migrate users from Crucible to Jira?

Tags: jira, atlassian-fisheye, atlassian-crucible

We have been using FishEye/Crucible for a while, and have recently added Jira. I would like to only have one list of users (which I presume will be in Jira). My question - is there a way that I can migrate the existing users to Jira in a way that their Crucible activities are not affected (that is, I would prefer to not just delete them all and re-enter them in Jira, as I'm concerned their history and preferences in Crucible would be lost).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received the following answer from Atlassian:  https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/177359/what-is-the-best-way-to-migrate-users-from-crucible-to-jira